# Printing issue with colors sampled using the eyedropper tool

Tags: print-design

I'm a pre-press worker as well as a graphic designer. I often encounter this problem when I use the Eyedropper Tool to sample a color in order to create a bleed.

On the monitor, colors show exactly same. However, the colors turns very different after being printed. (e.g. original dark blue, sampled color: light blue)

Does anyone know whats actually happening?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information than that. What software are you using?  I take it the job is in CMYK, but is the artwork you are sampling in the same colour mode. What kind of image are you sampling, raster, vector? Have you calibrated your monitor?. . .  so many questions . . .

Comment: I have to agree with the above, it sounds like you may be sampling an RGB item and putting it into a CMYK workspace, or however you are creating the bleed areas is an RGB item.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the actual application.... for example Shift-clicking with the eyedropper in Illustrator or InDesign *always* samples the screen *preview* (RGB) not the actual object. (InDesign actually throws up a warning telling you this) So, the monitor *calibration* plays a *huge* role in how accurate any eyedropper click may be.

It's better to check *numbers* if you can't directly select a colored object. Hover your cursor over an object and look at the **Info Panel** (in most apps). You'll see a readout of the color breakdown, use those numbers to create a new swatch/color.

Or check your numbers *after* using the eyedropper and applying the new color to ensure they match.

Answer (score 0):

check your separation preview to see the exact print registration of colors.
check one by one the overprinted shapes or text. maybe they are overlapped or overprinted.

[image]